# awareなDataTimeIndexのshiftによる、不可解なAmbiguousTimeErrorについて

Tags: python, python3, pandas

freq='D'のDateTimeIndexで、ニューヨーク時刻の2022/02/07を92日前にずらすとAmbiguousTimeErrorが発生します。

freq属性をNoneにすればエラーを回避できることが確認できましたが、現在の振る舞い/仕様が不可解で納得できずにいます。
タイムゾーンを変換するときに、夏時間によるあいまいさが発生するのは理解でできたのですが、freq属性の有無で振る舞いが変わることが理解できません。
この振る舞いは仕様（期待どおりの振る舞い）なのでしょうか？
もし仕様だとしたら、それを裏付ける背景/理由などがご存じでしょうか？

Windows10, Python 3.9.1, Pandas 1.4.1 で100%再現しました。

```
import platform
import pandas as pd
print(f'- Python:[{platform.python_version()}], Pandas:[{pd.__version__}]')

datetime_index = pd.DatetimeIndex([pd.Timestamp('2022-02-07',tz='America/New_York')], freq='D')
# datetime_index.freq = None # <---この行を実行するとエラー回避できた
print('入力:', datetime_index)

datetime_index = datetime_index.shift(periods=-92, freq='D')
print('出力:', datetime_index)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: エラーメッセージも画面キャプチャではなく、文字のまま質問に貼り付けて下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> この振る舞いは仕様（期待どおりの振る舞い）なのでしょうか？

ソースコードの通りに動作しているので仕様と言えるのでしょう、おそらく。。。
※ 本来であれば `shift` メソッドに `ceil` や `floor` メソッドと同様に `ambiguous` キーワードが用意されているとよいのですけれども。

最初に、`pandas.core.indexes.datetimelike.DatetimeIndexOpsMixin.shift` メソッドのソースコードは以下になります。

[pandas/datetimelike.py at 1.4.x · pandas-dev/pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1.4.x/pandas/core/indexes/datetimelike.py#L356)

```py
def shift(self: _T, periods: int = 1, freq=None) -> _T:
                  :

    arr = self._data.view()
    arr._freq = self.freq
    result = arr._time_shift(periods, freq=freq)
    return type(self)._simple_new(result, name=self.name)
```

ここで、`pandas.core.arrays.datetimelike.DatetimeLikeArrayMixin._time_shift` を呼び出しています。

[pandas/datetimelike.py at 1.4.x · pandas-dev/pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1.4.x/pandas/core/arrays/datetimelike.py#L1230)

```py
def _time_shift(
        self: DatetimeLikeArrayT, periods: int, freq=None
) -> DatetimeLikeArrayT:
                  :

    if freq is not None and freq != self.freq:
        if isinstance(freq, str):
            freq = to_offset(freq)
        offset = periods * freq
        return self + offset
                  :
```

今回の場合、`freq` は `shift` の parameter で `-92` です。そして、

```py
    datetime_index.freq = None
```

を実行した場合、`self.freq` は `None` になります。つまり、この `if` statement が成立して(`True`)、

```py
>>> datetime_index + (-92) * pd._libs.tslibs.to_offset('D')
DatetimeIndex(['2021-11-07 01:00:00-04:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, America/New_York]', freq=None)
```

が戻される事になります(DST は考慮されません)。

Comment: ありがとうございます。コードどおりの動作であることを知ることができてよかったです。

Answer (score 0):

**freq属性の有無** よりも **freq属性が'D'である** ことと、**時刻を指定していないので 00:00:00 を指定したと見做される** ことの組み合わせが原因と思われます。

[DateOffset objects - Time series / date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects)
pandasの上記説明に書かれている`'D'`より細かい単位の`'H'`,`'T'`,`'S'`,`'L'`,`'U'`,`'N'`を`freq=`に指定するとエラーは発生しません。

また`freq='D'`のままで`pd.Timestamp('2022-02-07',tz='America/New_York')`の`'2022-02-07'`の部分に午前2時以後の時刻を指定して`'2022-02-07 02:00'`や`'2022-02-07 23:59:59.999999999'`にするとエラーは発生しません。
しかし時刻部分に`00:00`から`01:59:59.999999999`までを指定していると同様のエラーになります。

こちらの記事で、`'Europe/Berlin'`のタイムゾーンだと`02:00`から`02:59:59.999999999`までが同様に曖昧な時間として扱われるようです。
[Why do I get 'Cannot infer dst time from '2017-10-29 02:04:15', try using the 'ambiguous' argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51872791/9014308)

この辺のIssueが関連してそうで修正されているケースもあるようですね。
[Fix naive-datetime timezone conversion when marshaling dataframes #1061](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/1061)
[Fix datetime timezone handling in data frames #2784](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/pull/2784)
[BUG: round() on tz-aware DateTimeIndex (spanning DST switch) throws AmbiguousTimeError as if tz-unaware #37485](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/37485)
[BUG: Timestamp.floor() method not able to handle DST change in local time #44287](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/44287)

だからまだ修正しきれていないバグの可能性もありそうです。
Issuesを検索して同様の物が無ければIssueを発行してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ありがとうございます。<https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/37485>にて起票すべきか確認しました。返信ないですが一旦ここまででよいのかなと思っています。